# SQLite: BLOB for storing large files?

Tags: .net, vb.net, sqlite, large-files

I want to store large files(over 100mb) in a sqlite database. I noticed, that its not good in performance. 
Do I have to store the files in a local folder, or do i have to rewrite my code?

```
       Shared Sub BlobToFile(ByVal Blob As Byte(), ByVal file As String)
        Dim MyData() As Byte = Blob
        Dim K As Long
        K = UBound(MyData)
        Dim fs As New FileStream _
         (file, FileMode.Create, _
          FileAccess.Write)
        fs.Write(MyData, 0, K)
        fs.Close()
        MyData = Nothing
        K = Nothing
    End Sub
    Shared Function FileToBlob(ByVal Filepath As String) As Byte()
        Dim fs As New FileStream _
     (Filepath, FileMode.Open, _
      FileAccess.Read)
        Dim MyData(fs.Length) As Byte
        fs.Read(MyData, 0, fs.Length)
        fs.Close()
        Return MyData
    End Function
'Then I Do this:
Dim x As New Sqliteparameter With {.Name ="@file", .value=Filetoblob("C:\Testfile.zip"), .DbType.Binary}
Dim y As New SqliteCommand With {.Commandtext = "INSERT INTO FILES(File) Values(@file);"}
y.Parameters.add(x)
y.Executenonquery()
```

Thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is generally best practice to not store large files inside a database unless there is support for it such as with mssql server. I would reccomend looking at just storing the location of the file in the database and storing the file in some sort of file system.